# ARCore: How to get depth (distance from camera) at any arbitrary pixel?

Tags: arcore

I have what I thought was a very simple need, which is to get a 2d array of distances from the camera many times per second (like a LIDAR); for example, a 10x10 array of samples that are interpolated across the screen. I just want the distance to whatever the pixel is showing. I thought ARCore should be easily capable of this because it's correlating all the pixels with past frames so it should know where everything is.

I thought I am supposed to use hitTest() for this. I could call hitTest() 100 times per second. But hitTest() usually gives no results or inaccurate results. For example, it might detect a table, but not a wall or anything else. And, hitTest() seems to be very slow and laggy so I can't call it 100 times per second.

Am I doing something wrong? Also, would Apple's ARKit be a better choice for my needs? Or do I need to resort to external hardware which is better for getting actual distance?

Comment: If none of these work I was also considering using a neural net that can guess the 3D depth just from an image, like https://github.com/ialhashim/DenseDepth . But I have concerns about whether this can be fast enough to do 10+ times per second, on a phone.

Answer (score 1):

ARcore does not currently support accurate depth sensing on the types of devices it can run on at this time (mid 2019).

See a note from the ARCore team here: https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues/206